# JavaScript: Adding query string to URL based on input fields values, if set?

Tags: javascript, input, query-string, getelementbyid, indexof

I have 5 input fields in a form and I would like to add their respective parameters and values, if set, to query string

What I am trying to do is to make it add **?** before the first parameter at the end of domain.tld, if there is none, and show the particular parameter with it's value of first input then if other input, add **&** and next parameter with the value, then **&** and rest of parameters and values as query string is structured and only add parameters and their values if there is value inserted in their respective inputs by element ID.

In the task it is required to add the query string with parameters and their values, if and only if there is respective input for them. Not sure why it does not work. This would have worked well with PHP's **strpos()** (already having similar functionality for a redirect elsewhere and it works) and **indexOf()** in JavaScript is kind of the equivalent of PHP's **strpos()**, right?. What I tried is provided below.

Somehow I am missing the continuation thinking the **url = url + ** part would suffice. In the end I want to show the URL in a textarea element. Just adding the parameters to URL and show result in texarea for copying on click for use. Already have the click to copy figured out.

```js
function parameterize() {
  var paramter0 = document.getElementById('parameter0').value;
  var parameter1 = document.getElementById('parameter1').value;
  var parameter2 = document.getElementById('parameter2').value;
  var parameter3 = document.getElementById('parameter3').value;
  var parameter4 = document.getElementById('parameter4').value;

  var url = 'https://domain.tld';

  if (paramter0) {
    if (indexOf(url, '?') !== false) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'paramter0=' + paramter0;
  }
  if (parameter1) {
    if (indexOf(url, '?') !== false) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter1=' + parameter1;
  }
  if (parameter2) {
    if (indexOf(url, '?') !== false) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter2=' + parameter2;
  }
  if (parameter3) {
    if (indexOf(url, '?') !== false) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter3=' + parameter3;
  }
  if (parameter4) {
    if (indexOf(url, '?') !== false) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter4=' + parameter4;
  }
}
document.getElementById('paramed_url').innerHTML = url;

document.getElementById('add_parameters').addEventListener('click', parameterize);
```

```html
<div id="parameters" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter0 0:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter0" name="parameter0" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 1:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter1" name="parameter1" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 2:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter2" name="parameter2" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 3:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter3" name="parameter3" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 4:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter4" name="parameter4" maxlength="64">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="add_parameters" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        APPLY
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your current output?

Comment: This will be way easier if you would collect the inputs in an array.

Comment: I made you a [mcve]- It gives an error. - indexOf is not defined

Comment: Syntax missing here for indexOf(). It should be url.indexOf('?'). Fore more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: also, to extend on @Sagar's comment, you should compare like this: `url.indexOf('?') > -1` because it never returns false but `-1` if not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's what you want [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cu7186hm/1/).

```
document.getElementById('add_parameters').addEventListener('click', parametrize);

function parametrize() {
  let url = 'https://domain.tld';
  let params = {};
  document.querySelectorAll('#parameters input.select-selected').forEach((element) => {
    if (element.value.length > 0)
        params[element.id] = element.value;
  });
  let esc = encodeURIComponent;
  let query = Object.keys(params)
    .map(k => esc(k) + '=' + esc(params[k]))
    .join('&');
  url += '?' + query;
  alert(url);
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! (bow)

Comment: Now I see when I click on apply without any values in the inputs it only adds ? to the domain.tld/script.php part. I will have to check if query.lenght < 0 to avoid this. Any othe rideas? Seems like I have to figure out a jQuery example for this on a table I use jQuery, too. Maybe it will be easier there. Will see. May try the other answer, too.

Comment: @lion So did you try the other answers?

Comment: @mplungjan, no. The answer of marc_s worked well. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I see `but somehow I did not manage to implement it`, `Works well here. I will give it a try. Picked as answer.` so I was just curious

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error as I pointed out in a comment: indexOf is not defined

If you insist, it is `if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {` to test if there is a `?`

I ASSUME you do not just want to submit a form in which case you do not need any processing, the form submit will do it for you

Here is how to append parameters to a URL using the [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

Add this to get Internet Explorer support

`<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>`

**NOTE:** I changed the name to parameterize

```js
var url = new URL('https://domain.tld');

function parameterize() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".select-selected").forEach(function(inp) {
   url.searchParams.append(inp.name,inp.value); // if (inp.value) ...
  })
  console.log(url)
}

document.getElementById('add_parameters').addEventListener('click', parameterize);
```

```html
<div id="parameters" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter0 0:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter0" name="parameter0" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 1:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter1" name="parameter1" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 2:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter2" name="parameter2" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 3:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter3" name="parameter3" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 4:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter4" name="parameter4" maxlength="64">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" id="add_parameters" class="btn btn-primary">
        APPLY
        </button>
</div>
```

**jQuery** Note I am here testing the value. If nothing is filled in, you get the original URL

```js
var url = new URL('https://domain.tld');

function parameterize() {
  $(".select-selected").each(function() {
   if (this.value) url.searchParams.append(this.name,this.value); // only if value entered
  })
  console.log(url)
}

$('#add_parameters').on('click', parameterize);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parameters" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter0 0:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter0" name="parameter0" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 1:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter1" name="parameter1" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 2:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter2" name="parameter2" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 3:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter3" name="parameter3" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 4:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter4" name="parameter4" maxlength="64">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" id="add_parameters" class="btn btn-primary">
        APPLY
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention and effort to help but somehow I did not manage to implement it and I picked the answer of OceanRages.

Comment: @lion Please note I corrected the spelling of parameterize  - perhaps that is why my version did not work for you?

Comment: Most probably that is why. I may check when I can and will let you know. Thanks again!! Unfortunately, I can't upvote maybe because of my account reputation.

Comment: Looks like I can't accept 2 answers at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think this will work for my case because sometimes I have extra things in the box before and after the URL, so OceanRages' answer was better for my case. Your answer is great, too, but hard to implement on my case. Also I need to make a jQuery variant because it will be needed for DataTables init where this URL will come into play. Maybe it will be easier there. Have to check it all. It is huge code. :)

Comment: Yes it will work if they field has the correct clasnames. I added a jQuery version

Comment: Works well here. I will give it a try. Picked as answer. Both answers seem to pull this off nicely.

Comment: I see that URL.searchParams is not supported in IE. Not sure how many IE users this will get but I have to find a way for IE, too, I guess. Any suggestions?

Comment: Very clever, will only load code if needed: `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you collect the inputs in an array, you can just filter and join them, no matter how many parameters you have. That way you don't have to write new code every time you add a parameter, since the start of the query string `?` will always go before the array join and the `&` seperator between the array items. I moved the .parameter clas to the inputs since it made more sense ther eto me than on the labels.

```js
const create_uri = () => {
  const parameters = [ ...document.querySelectorAll( '.parameter' ) ];
  const root = 'https://domain.tld';
  const query_string = parameters.map( input => input.value ? `${ input.id }=${ input.value }` : '' );
  return `${ root }?${ encodeURIComponent( query_string.join( '&' )) }`;
};

const parameterize = () => {
  const uri = create_uri();
  console.log( uri );
};

document.getElementById('add_parameters').addEventListener('click', parameterize);
```

```html
<div id="parameters" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>parameter 0:</label>
      <input type="text" class="select-selected parameter" id="parameter0" name="parameter0" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>parameter 1:</label>
      <input type="text" class="select-selected parameter" id="parameter1" name="parameter1" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>parameter 2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="select-selected parameter" id="parameter2" name="parameter2" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>parameter 3:</label>
      <input type="text" class="select-selected parameter" id="parameter3" name="parameter3" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label>parameter 4:</label>
      <input type="text" class="select-selected parameter" id="parameter4" name="parameter4" maxlength="64">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="add_parameters" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  APPLY
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: searchParams.append does all that for you - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you don't want to apply a special processing to your inputs, all you are doing is strictly equivalent to this (added `type="submit"` to the button to submit the form):

```html
<div id="parameters" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 
 <form action="https://domain.tld" method="get">
  
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter0 0:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter0" name="parameter0" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 1:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter1" name="parameter1" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 2:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter2" name="parameter2" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 3:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter3" name="parameter3" maxlength="64">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label class="parameter">parameter 4:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter4" name="parameter4" maxlength="64">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="add_parameters" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        APPLY
  </button>

 </form>
 
</div>
```

**Explanation**: by using `method="get"` in a `form` tag, all inputs values will be passed in the URL on submission with the format `url?{input1_name}={input1_value}&{input2_name}={input2_value}...`, exactly like you are doing in a custom way

Comment: Now the question has been edited, this answer is useless, however I don't delete it in case a inexperienced coder arrives here in the future

Answer (score -1):

Corrected your `indexOf()` syntax else everything is good

```js
function parameterize() {
  var paramter0 = document.getElementById('parameter0').value;
  var parameter1 = document.getElementById('parameter1').value;
  var parameter2 = document.getElementById('parameter2').value;
  var parameter3 = document.getElementById('parameter3').value;
  var parameter4 = document.getElementById('parameter4').value;

  var url = 'https://domain.tld';

  if (paramter0) {
    if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'paramter0=' + paramter0;
  }
  if (parameter1) {
    if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter1=' + parameter1;
  }
  if (parameter2) {
    if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter2=' + parameter2;
  }
  if (parameter3) {
    if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter3=' + parameter3;
  }
  if (parameter4) {
    if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
      var symbol_insert = '&';
    } else {
      var symbol_insert = '?';
    }
    url = url + symbol_insert + 'parameter4=' + parameter4;
  }
  console.log(url)
}

document.getElementById('add_parameters').addEventListener('click', parameterize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="parameters" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <label class="parameter">parameter0 0:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter0" name="parameter0" maxlength="64">
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <label class="parameter">parameter 1:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter1" name="parameter1" maxlength="64">
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <label class="parameter">parameter 2:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter2" name="parameter2" maxlength="64">
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <label class="parameter">parameter 3:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter3" name="parameter3" maxlength="64">
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <label class="parameter">parameter 4:</label> <input type="text" class="select-selected" id="parameter4" name="parameter4" maxlength="64">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="add_parameters" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    APPLY
    </button>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```